# How to set position x and y for dragable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which is using dragable jquery adn jquery UI:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
#draggable {border: 0px solid black; background-color : transparent; width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
                start: function (e, ui) {
                    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                    $("#start").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
                },
                stop: function (e, ui) {
                    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                    $("#end").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
                },
                drag: function (e, ui) {
                    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                    $("#current").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
                }

            });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">Test</div>
 start Position:<span id="start"></span>
    <br />
    End Position:<span id="end"></span>
    <br />
    Dragging Position<span id="current"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to set position x and y for object. After page load object will be for example on coordinates x=50 and y=50. I tried to put start var relX=50 but it is not working

Comment: You want to set the initial position of the element?

Comment: Yes. start position after page load

Comment: So set the position of the element with CSS.

Comment: Did you try http://api.jquery.com/css/?